# Angular Material: mat-checkbox vertical alignment of checkbox

Tags: angular-material

I can't seem to override the defaults to vertically align the checkbox relative to the checkbox label.  Searched for a while but nothing has worked.  See example image:

[image]

Should be like:

[image]

Have tried the following:

```
.mat-checkbox-inner-container {
    margin: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<label><b>Home Type</b></label>
    <mat-checkbox>Entire place<br><small class="text-muted">Have a place to yourself</small></mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox>Private room<br><small class="text-muted">Have your own room and share some common spaces</small></mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox>Shared room<br><small class="text-muted">Stay in a shared space, like a common room</small></mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, I haven't been back to revisit it.  There are a couple of solutions below suggested which I will try when I get time.  Please comment below them if they work for you.

Comment: Pat M's answer below worked if I added that styling to a global stylesheet, but did not work if I added that class to a component's stylesheet. I'm guessing Angular's view-encapsulation prevents the component's style from overriding the material styling. Hope this helps

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Similar to Craig's answer but as a descendant of .mat-checkbox.mat-accent to spare the need of using "!important"

```
.mat-checkbox.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-inner-container {
    margin: 2px 8px auto 0;
}
```

or using sass/less

```
.mat-checkbox.mat-accent {
   .mat-checkbox-inner-container {
      margin: 2px 8px auto 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you have to add this to a global stylesheet? I tried pasting this into the stylesheet for one of my components but it didn't work, and I would like to avoid making it a global style..

Comment: Unfortuntely, it seems that it can't be applied from within an angular framework component for example. Since the classes mat-accent & mat-checkbox-inner-container are generated by angular material (from <mat-checkbox>) after the angular component has been executed and it's style applied.

I also need to use some material.scss globally for these cases.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured. I ended up adding it to a global sass sheet but wrapping it in my own class to avoid affecting the styles of other checkboxes throughout the app

Answer (score 4):

Just run into the same problem. I used the following to solve it (unfortunately needs the dreaded !important):

```
.mat-checkbox-inner-container {
  margin: 2px 8px auto 0 !important;
}
```

I found I had to adjust the top margin (2px in this case) to get the layout beside the label to look correct.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to achieve this (I'm using Angular/Material 7.x) by resetting the margins the checkbox container uses.

Note that I have had to apply an additional `translateY` to account for the box's border-width, and reset the wrap on the label so the text doesn't try to stay on one line.

*your.component.scss*

```
:host {
  ::ng-deep {
    .mat-checkbox-inner-container {
      margin-top: initial;
      margin-bottom: initial;
      transform: translateY(2px); // value of checkbox border-width
    }
    .mat-checkbox-label {
      white-space: normal; // wrap label text
    }
  }
}
```

[StackBlitz Fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ifkx8n?file=app%2Fcheckbox-overview-example.scss)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but below worked for me – I honestly didn't even know `auto` worked with vertical alignment, but I guess it does ‍♂️:

```css
  .mat-checkbox-inner-container {
      margin-top: 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <h1>LABEL CHECKBOX</h1>
  <mat-checkbox class="mat-checkbox-layout"><strong>FINE</strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicingelit. Optio vitae molestiae nemo magni odio voluptate corporis veniam sapiente earum fugiat rem,maiores et placeat qui iure, nobis ipsam sintenim.</mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox class="mat-checkbox-layout"><strong>OK</strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Optio vitae molestiae nemo magni odio voluptate corporis veniam sapiente earum fugiat rem, maiores et placeat qui iure, nobis ipsam sintenim.</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

**And the CSS is this (I create css class identically with angular css class)**

```
.mat-checkbox-layout {
  text-align: justify;
}

::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-layout .mat-checkbox-layout {
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:host {
  ::ng-deep {
    .mat-checkbox-layout {
      align-items: end!important;
    }
    .mat-checkbox-label {
      white-space: normal; // wrap label text
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello please add additional information as to how/why this answer helps solve the question. Please consider reviewing the answering guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

In "@angular/material": "16.2.12", you need to use mdc format.

.mat-checkbox-inner-container does not appear to be used anymore.

Use this instead

```
.mdc-checkbox  {
    margin: 0px 8px auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a fast solution which is not related to ng-material

you can put your "mat-checkbox" into "li" element and align your "ul" by setting the number of columns like this:

```
<ul style="columns:2">
    <li>
        <mat-checkbox>Entire place<br><small class="text-muted">Have a place to yourself</small></mat-checkbox>
    </li>
    <li>
        <mat-checkbox>Private room<br><small class="text-muted">Have your own room and share some common spaces</small></mat-checkbox>
    </li>
    <li>
        <mat-checkbox>Shared room<br><small class="text-muted">Stay in a shared space, like a common room</small></mat-checkbox>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That just puts it into 2 columns.  I am trying to move the check box to align with the top of the text.